# response = request.urlopen(url) not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I've tried, but it's always wrong.
is there a solution? So here is the code I am using:

```
from urllib import request

url = "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2554/2554.txt"

response = request.urlopen(url)

raw = response.read().decode('utf8')

type(raw)
```

[this is an error that happened**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG4Ik.png)**

Comment: Please do not include images of the traceback, it should be as formatted text in your question. In this case, we can't even see the bottom of the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

The url `http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2554/2554.txt`  does not exist. Simply try pasting the url in your browser.

Try it with a valid url, your code works!